Older movie with a device that records dreams
So this was a rather odd, serious movie, probably from around the 90s. The one distinct feature I remember was that about half way or so, the main characters move to a bunker-in-the-desert type environment. 
There, one of them (a woman if I remember correctly), uses this device able to visualize and record a person's dreams. Especially after they get to the bunker/desert location, she becomes obsessed and addicted to the device and re-watching her dreams. 
That's about the most unique part, so if you've seen it - you may recall it! Thanks, and any clues will be appreciated! 

Thank you so much Walt! That appears to be the exact movie!

Could be Wim Wenders' sci-fi film Until the End of the World from 1991 with William Hurt. From IMDb:

Set in 1999, a woman (Dommartin) has a car accident with some bank robbers, who enlist her help to take the bank money to a drop in Paris. On the way she runs into another fugitive from the law (Hurt), an American who is being chased by the CIA. The charges are false, he claims. They want to confiscate a device his father invented which allows anyone to record their dreams and vision.

They end up in a cave in the Australian Outback and the heroine becomes addicted to this device. Here's the trailer:



